# nightwatch - alter page object elements

Tags: css, xpath, nightwatch.js

Is it possible to alter an element in the "elements" section in "page object" while the program is running? I create objects during the run and I have to check whether the object names exist.

I followed the example from [here](https://github.com/nightwatchjs/nightwatch/issues/821):

Object Page:

```
module.exports = {
    url:  function() {
        return 'https://' + this.api.globals.host + '/#/products/';
    },
    elements: {
        product: ".product[data-product-name='%s']"
    },
    comands: [{
        el: function(elementName, data) {
            var element = this.elements[elementName.slice(1)];
            return util.format(element.selector, data);
        }
    }]
};
```

Test Program:

```
'my test': function (browser) {
  var page = browser.page.myPage();
  page.click(page.el('@product', 'milk')); // .product[data-product-name='milk']
}
```

It works fine, so far. Although it returns a selector string and this string is correct. But I encounter two problems:

1) The test is searching for a string name, hence, I use the **`XPath`** selector, but **`Nightwatch`** switch back to "CSS selector". Is there a way to keep Nightwatch in **`XPath`** mode?

[image]

2) While the "var page" object above uses the page object pattern it is not possible to pass an argument as a string it has to be an "element" from the "elements" section specified in my page object file. Does the example only works because it is a "CSS selector"?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need add a `selector` and `locateStrategy` field in elements to specify you want xpath, because default is using CSS in page object.

```
elements: {
    product:{
        locateStrategy :'xpath',
        selector : "//product[@data-product-name='%s']"
    }
}
```

You should also have a function that does the click for you inside the page object.